# Can high energy photoelectrons damage cell membranes?

Tags: cell-membrane, electrophysiology, radiation

I've read that in addition to ionizing radiation causing damage to DNA through direct absorption, but DNA can also be damaged through photoelectrons with enough energy.  The thing I was wondering is what kind of energy (in electron volts) would or might photoelectrons need to damage or penetrate the cellular membrane (like if x-rays excite photoelectrons outside of cells)?